# Adding to .htaccess line to solve routing

Tags: php, .htaccess

We have Drupal installed in **/www/var/**
And we have other system installed in **/www/var/othersystem/**

Drupal .htacess file is very complex (made not by me).

I wrote there (/var/www/.htaccess)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteRule ^othersystem - [L]
```

So to make Drupal engine not handle othersystem's pages

But when I am trying to access othersystem's admin at

**/var/www/othersystem/admin/**

Drupal again handles it and throws 404 error.

What line should add to /var/www/.htaccess to not handle **/var/www/othersystem/admin/** link?

Addition: 
**/var/www/othersystem/admin/.htaccess**

```
AddType application/octet-stream csv
AuthName "Some CMS"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /var/www/othersystem/admin/.passwd
require valid-user
```

Comment: Make sure this rule is your very first rule.

Comment: Then how is it that it doesn't work?
I also thought about it at first..

Comment: oh, i misunderstood you. it's first, surely

Comment: And what is your full URL for `othersystem` application?

Comment: full URL to admin is /var/www/othersystem/admin. I just checked

Comment: That is URL that is file system path. I believe it is `http://domain.com/othersystem/admin` Is there any .htaccess in `/var/www/othersystem/` OR `/var/www/othersystem/admin`?

Comment: Yes, there are, but they don't change anything. If I delete /var/www/.htaccess, it fixed the problem...

Answer (score 0):

There should be a line like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Which says to redirect pretty much everything to index.php.   Just add another RewriteCond

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/othersystem/.*$
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

I believe (but not sure) that you could also put a new .htaccess file in the folder you want to ignore, with just:

```
RewriteEngine Off
```

Comment: Thanks, thats better than I wrote but either it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: I can add that when I delete /var/www/.htaccess file, /var/www/othersystem/admin/ works ok and I can access the page

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line on top of your `/var/www/othersystem/.htaccess` to reset 404 handler being used by Drupal:

```
ErrorDocument 404 default
```

Comment: I did that, but the situation doesn't change... When I enter othersystem/somenotexistentpage, it shows othersystem 404 page, but when I enter othersystem/admin, it shows Drupal 404 page

Comment: I added /var/www/othersystem/admin/.htaccess to description

Comment: Try adding this same line on top of `/var/www/othersystem/admin/.htaccess` also.

Comment: Again that doesnt help((

Comment: For testing purpose can your comment out `ErrorDocument 404` line in `/var/www/.htaccess`

Comment: If I comment it in .htaccess Drupal handles it anyway and shows 404 page

Comment: I wanted to know whether default Apache 404 comes in that case or a Drupal 404 error message.

Comment: That simply means Drupal is still handling those requests and none of our trucks have worked so far.

Comment: Are you using  different domains by any chance for Drupal and for othersystem?

Comment: Just for testing, if you change 1st rule to: `RewriteRule ^othersystem - [F,NC]` does it block everything under `/othersystem/`?

Comment: How about adding: `RewriteRule ^ - [F]` rule in `/othersystem /admin/.htaccess`

Comment: Again I get Drupal 404 error page. And if I place it in /othersystem/.htaccess, it works ok and blocks all /othersystem/* pages

Comment: Well that means something is a mystery with `othersystem/admin/` If it caused forbidden in `/othersystem/` it should have been same for `/othersystem/admin` also.